# Run Program on Startup?

Tags: windows, boot

How is it possible to have an executable run automatically on startup? Is it possible by having a shortcut to the .exe in the startup folder in the All programs section of the start menu? If that is correct, what is the full directory of the startup folder?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: I suppose Windows 7. If not it would be equally interesting to know about windows xp and vista also.

Comment: Im sorry if this is amateurish, but would it be possible for an explanation of how to use the following code?

 Private Const cPGM = "C:\VB Forum\startup\TestStartup.exe"

   Dim oShell As IWshShell_Class
   Set oShell = New IWshShell_Class
   oShell.RegWrite "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyVBApp", _
                   cPGM, "REG_SZ"

thanks for your patience

Comment: that will set a registry key that allows "C:\VB Forum\startup\TestStartup.exe" to run at startup

Answer (score 7):

There are many options, the Startup folder being only one of them.

A detailed guide is available here: http://oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/startup_0401.html

The most popular option these days is the registry - see the guide link above for details.

Comment: That's the answer. You don't need to look any further.

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way is to create a registry entry, such as in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run`.  The key needs to be of type `REG_SZ` (0-terminated string) and contain a unique name as `Name` and the program's full executable path as `Data`.

Comment: I disagree. The registry has less transparency to the average user than the startup folder. Users don't generally like it when programs add startup items of dubious necessity.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another method is to use the task scheduler found under accessories/system tools.  Create a task that launches the program at startup.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: Be wary of non-English versions here!! There are known ways to get special folders under Windows.

Comment: I notices the tags didn't include a tag for any programming language so I assumed he just wanted a path. I think maybe his question if not asking for code example should be placed on superuser instead.

Comment: You should still use the environment variables. `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Answer (score 0):

the simpliest way is to create a shortcut and to drag it it Startup folder (drag over start button, programs, start and drop it there)

If you want to see the path, just r-click on startup folder and select open