# How can I add the program that starts with my PC?

Tags: boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run Program on Startup?](https://superuser.com/questions/125942/run-program-on-startup)

How can I add the program that starts with my PC?

Comment: You probably need to register to be able to add programs to their database

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/125942/run-program-on-startup

Comment: Is your question about adding an application to their known startup database? Or is it about adding startup files to your personal pc?

Comment: I think you should ask this question on their forums....http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the start menu startup folder method, follow these steps:

**First Copy the program you want to have start up automatically**

[image: copy file]

**Then Go Start >>  All Programs >> Start up**

[image]

**Right-Click on Start up and select open**

[image: open]

**A Window Pops up**

**Right Click and paste shortcut**

[image: paste shortcut]

**You are done**

[image]

Comment: huzza, good effort :)

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to put a shortcut to it in the startup folder of your start menu. (assuming you mean on windows)

Answer (score 1):

The site you linked to is mentioning a way to check your startup files in Windows when you are looking for a virus, unwanted application, or just cleaning up a machine. They are also talking about a registered database of known startup applications. You didn't mention which version of Windows you are running? I am going to assume this is for Windows.

Is your question about adding an application to their known startup database?  Or is it about adding startup files to your personal pc?

If your wanting just to add startup files on your pc, there are two ways to do it:

1. Through the startup folder in your start menu. You can just add a shortcut to the app you want run to that folder.
2. Through the registry.  I don't recommend this way unless your comfortable editing the registry.

See here for more detailed instructions: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/36665.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have Windows and that you want an easy way to do (that is use GUI). An alternative to putting a shortcut in the startup folder is using [Quick Startup](http://www.glarysoft.com/products/utilities/quick-startup/) and the best part is that its free.

Comment: 'Quick Startup' is pretty useful. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

That site is operated by *PC Review*.  Email them using the "Contact Us" link on the site's "About Us" menu and tell them about the program you want added.