# How can a PowerShell script be automatically run on startup?

Tags: script, powershell, autostart

I have a PowerShell script to monitor an image folder. I need it to run automatically on startup.

I tried to use MSConfig, but I could not find it in that list.

How can I have the script automatically run on startup?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add the program that starts with my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/187158/how-can-i-add-the-program-that-starts-with-my-pc), [Run Program on Startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/125942/run-program-on-startup)

Comment: There is no difference between adding a PS script and any other executable to startup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy ps1 into this folder, create it if necessary.

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Startup
```

Comment: I put a script there that should continue to run in the background, but it never seems to start... hmmm. I'm on Win10

Answer (score 0):

> On Windows 10 personal machine

I added my startup bat script to this folder:

```
C:\Users\bsheps\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

The script runs automatically every time I log in to my computer.

Comment: *The script runs automatically every time I start my computer.* - more like every time you log in