# Display program over logon screen windows

Tags: windows, powershell, c#, login-screen

I would like to display a program (just a classic window, who get all the screen) for asking a question on login screen or lock screen.

I already get my popup look like windows BSOD screen.

It's for executing some scans during night but we don't know if some user will be there so we want to force the lock screen and display a windows saying we are currently doing somme maintenance task. 
If anyone is in front of the computer he can validate or discard the task. If he is ok for doing right now, we start scan, if he is not we give him back control. If no response is catch in some delay, we start our task.

I already get some information and code (in C#), but I'm not really programmer (just doing few thing like script, it's not really writing program). I work more under system and I don't know how to adapt the code that I found in PowerShell.

Link to C# code :
https://web.archive.org/web/20150205131626/http://calebdelnay.com/blog/2012/01/displaying-a-program-on-the-windows-secure-desktop

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We are here help you with PowerShell code you've written and having issues with, which you are not showing.

You can write script that executes at computer start, log on, log off, shutdown, etc. It's a very common practice and has noting to really do with PowerShell, but setting the Scheduled task or System policy or registry setting to run whatever.

http://superuser.com/questions/187158/how-can-i-add-the-program-that-starts-with-my-pc

http://superuser.com/questions/125942/run-program-on-startup

Even the link you point to is using a scheduled task to execute this, covered in the 'The high Level Concept' section.

Yet, anything you'd do would have to start after that code or you'd need to tweak that code to add what is needed to run with it.

As a rule, never ever run any code, from any where, from any one that you do not fully understand. You could cause major irreparable damage to your environment. You say you are not a programmer, but you are trying to use code that acts at the [MSGINA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SecAuthN/customizing-winlogon) (WinLogon level) and force another time to fire as a child to that process.

This is extremely deep level stuff that a non-programmer, or one that understands core OS level stuff would be well advised to stay away from. I get what you are after, but IMHO, hire a consultant to come in an help, to provide assurance you have all completely thought thru and evaluated this use case.

Noting is stopping you from going your own way of course. But, just saying.

***Update for OP***

As for ...

> What I don't understand is how make the DLL import in powershell.

... read these.

https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/10/27/load-a-custom-dll-from-powershell
https://serverfault.com/questions/455163/how-to-properly-add-net-assemblies-to-powershell-session

As for ...

> Marshalling – what is it and why do we need it?

… this is not a PowerShell construct, but a C/C+/C++/C#, etc., language construct. Read this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240804/marshalling-what-is-it-and-why-do-we-need-it

Comment: I'm not showing powershell code, because it isn't at this time powershell code for showing my windows on this screen. I just got a Pop Up, really basic. I already made my sheduled task for executing this popup with a log file. And I don't see my popup, i just got my log file saying that there isn't any answer from the user (normal because there is no window showing for give my answer). I don't run the code in C#, I try to before understand what it's doing. I get that he take the token of the system, duplicate him, remplace the session ID on the token and execute my process with my new token.

Comment: What I don't understand is how make the DLL import in powershell. What is MarhalAs ? Stuff like that.... I know it touch to the core OS and it's gonna be hard to do, but I want to try, maybe i'll give up because I'm gonna face to a wall, and maybe it's gonna success.

Comment: See my update for you...

Comment: Thanks, I'll read your link. Keep you in touch.